# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rows')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

```js
const client = require('../../db')
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); //req.body

app.listen(8670, ()=>{
    console.log("Sever is now listening at port 5000");
})

client.connect();

app.get("/location", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { city } = req.query;
      const { district } = req.query;
      const location = await client.query('SELECT * FROM location WHERE city ILIKE $1 and district ILIKE $2',
        [`%${city}%`],[`%${district}%`]);
      res.json(location.rows);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  });
```

I want to write search query in my locaiton table, e.g. to run the search query from location table without sequelize.

I am getting this error while running the code:

> error:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'rows')

Comment: First please add the actual code to your question, not a picture of it. Second the error message is pretty clear, `location` is undefined, so when you try to do `location.rows` then you are trying to access a property "rows" of undefined. You need to figure out why your SQL client query is returning undefined

Comment: @Jayce444 ı added codes. Actually at first i could not get error only in single parameter pointers, but i got error in checking second parameter

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you this:
Connect to your database where you are querying from with a client like DBeaver or any other tool you know.
https://dbeaver.io/

Check if your query turns the data you are exspecting.
Check the Url with the query params /?city=mycity&district=mydistrict

Debug your code on the queryParams or console.log them.
Also console.log(location).
If your query doesnt return data, it most likly will be null. If not analyse it, maybe it indicates an error, or your data are not in a "rows" array.

Consider that an array like rows, is returned only if you have more than 1 result of datarows, otherways it returns most likely an object.

If this doesnt help, post your code completly , atleast your client. Which db are you using ecc.